# Proof for the expression of Boyle's temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature, states-of-matter

Boyle's temperature is the temperature in which a real gas behaves like an ideal gas under a certain range of pressure. In my book, it is given that Boyle's temperature ($T_{b}$):

$T_{b}=\frac{a}{Rb}$

But why? I asked my teacher and he gave no answer. I couldn't find a proof of this anywhere on the internet. Please give a rigorous proof of this.

Comment: It's derived in this video https://youtu.be/rg_h31QS534

Answer (score 2):

If you recall the [Van der Waals equation](http://Van%20der%20Waals%20equation),
$$\left(p+\frac{a}{V_m}\right)(V_m-b)=RT$$
where $V_m=V/n_\text{moles}$ is the molar volume.
$$p=\frac{RT}{V-b}-\frac{a}{V^2}=\frac{RT}{V}\left(1-\frac{b}{V}\right)^{-1}-\frac{a}{V^2}$$
and using the binomial expansion, the terms in brackets can be expanded into a series, resulting in
$$\frac{pV}{RT}=1+\frac{1}{V}\left(b-\frac{a}{RT}\right)+\left(\frac{b}{V}\right)^2+\left(\frac{b}{V}\right)^3+\cdots$$
The Boyle temperature $T_B$ is defined by $B(T_B)=0$ and  hence
$$T_B=\frac{a}{Rb}\Rightarrow T_B=\frac{27T_c}{8} $$
Near Boyle's temperature
$$\frac{pV}{RT}\approx 1+\mathcal{O}\left(\left(\frac{b}{V}\right)^2\right)\approx 1$$
So real gas approximately behave like ideal gases.